# How do you bake with particle instance?

Tags: particles, texture-baking, hair, polycount

So I've used a low poly hair card with *Particle Instance* modifier to create fur. but it's quite heavy by the end, and I wanted to reduce the poly count if possible. how would you guys do it?

I was thinking maybe about baking it into a low poly, but I'm not sure if it'll work. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, this is my first model I've made and I have never tried baking before. I've tried google for hours, but I don't think all the baking tutorials can really help. Really appreciate all the help.

[image: screenshot 1]this is my model

[image: screenshot 2]but the fur is too high poly

[image: screenshot 3] I was thinking about using the vertex group from the body, solidifying it, and baking the fur into it, but I'm not sure if that'll work.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Blunder -- I think you intended to provide a link "[this model]" but it didn't take.

Comment: @james_t Yeah, the enter key sent the unfinished comment >,<

Comment: I think you have way too many hair cards (particles). Have a look at [this model](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/ammit-classic-fbb8a3d81791401d89a1f18256d0e4c9) it also uses hair cards. You can see them when you activate wireframe mode. (From far away it looks a bit odd but great when you get closer). Here is the full article: https://sketchfab.com/blogs/community/tutorial-real-time-fur-hair/

Comment: If you want to bake the particles (no hair cards) you need to convert them to a mesh (= a few million vertices!).  Then bake the particle mesh to the low-poly body. Bake type = *Diffuse Color*. To make the strands a bit thicker you can convert the mesh to curves, extrude them (curve settings) and convert them to a mesh again. Here is a baked example (no extrusion):
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239984/baking-of-a-hair-cap-doesnt-work/240006#240006

Comment: If you look at many hair tutorials, low poly hair is not made from blender physics hair.  Perhaps you might investigate some of these tutorials, or perhaps using a distort (with texture) or other pseudo technique like https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56537/111042

Comment: thanks every for the resource, u guys are awesome :D